# I have listview connected to database, when i click on any item in listview i want to fetch data for the particular item in next activity

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Here is the Listview I want it to fetch data for a particular item from Database and fetch it to 2nd Activity and put it in the Edittext.

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mArrayList.clear();
        ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
        final List<DatabaseAccounts> data = dB.getallrows();
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);


        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                DatabaseAccounts dbAccount = data.get(position);


                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Diary2.class);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        for(DatabaseAccounts dbb : data){
            mArrayList.add(dbb.getState());
        }
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mArrayList);
        list.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to implement **Parcelable** interface in your class:

```
public class Student implements Parcelable {

        int id;
        String name;

        public Student(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;

        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }


        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dest.writeInt(id);
            dest.writeString(name);
        }

        public Student(Parcel in) {
            id = in.readInt();
            name = in.readString();
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<Student> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Student>() {
            public Student createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Student(in);
            }

            public Student[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Student[size];
            }
        };
    }
```

**And the list**

```
ArrayList<Student> arraylist = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

**Code from Calling activity**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("mylist", arraylist);
intent.putExtras(bundle);       
this.startActivity(intent);
```

**Code on called activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);   

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    ArrayList<Student> arraylist = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("mylist");
}
```